# How to add botman 2.0 to existing laravel 5.6 project?

Tags: laravel-5, facebook-messenger-bot

I have an existing laravel project. I tried installing botman using "composer require botman/botman" but there are errors preventing me from adding botman:

```
Problem 1
   - Conclusion: don't install botman/botman 2.3.3
   - Conclusion: don't install botman/botman 2.3.2
   - Conclusion: don't install botman/botman 2.3.1
   - Conclusion: remove symfony/http-foundation v4.1.1
```

and more lines.

I also tried "composer require botman/studio-addons" but it only use version 1.2 of botman.

Comment: i don't think its gonna be possible, botman requires `symfony/http-foundation: 2.8.*|3.0.*|3.1.*|3.2.*|3.3.*|3.4.*|4.0.*` while laravel 5.6 requires `symfony/http-foundation: 4.1.*`

Comment: I think it is possible since I have created a laravel botman app with laravel 5.6 version.
What I want to do is add botman in my other existing laravel project.

Comment: laravel requires `symfony/http-foundation: ~4.0`, try removing `symfony/http-foundation: 4.1` and replacing it with `4.0` and everything should work fine.